# Advanced Custom Fields - Repeat choices array in several field groups based on 1 field

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

Context: I have a section on my site that shows a table of allowed/not allowed software. The value is set with AFC. I am future proofing the process of adding new software to that table as I will be moving on soon.

Goal: I want there to be one place where my value:label array can be updated and then the 6 separate fields automatically match. Basically like setting a variable and calling it in the 'choices' section of each field. I'm not sure how to do that.

[Here is an image of the area I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ymEv.png)
Here is a short example list to work off of for the array:

```
aws : Amazon Web Services (AWS)
google-drive : Google Drive
gmail : Gmail
gcp : Google Cloud Platform (GCP)
ect...
```

So say anything I do to change the choices in Allowed Software also updates the choices in Disallowed Software, if_oried, if_irb, ect...

Each one of these fields pulls from the same choices but the checked values are different depending on the page.

```
$a_softwares = get_field('allowed_software');
$d_softwares = get_field('disallowed_software');
$if_oried = get_field('if_oried');
$if_irb = get_field('if_irb');
$if_deidentify = get_field('if_deidentify');
$if_access = get_field('if_access');
```

I build a small array

```
$choices = array(
    "Amazon Web Service's (AWS)" => 'aws',
    'Google Drive' => 'google-drive',
    'Gmail' => 'gmail'
);
```

Then just to test if it printed, I put `<php? print $choices ?>` into the default value section of a text field, then called the field back into the php file:

```
<?php
$show_choices = get_field('test');

<?php echo $show_choices; ?>
?>
```

And nothing is printed where I hoped this would be printed

```
aws : Amazon Web Services (AWS)
google-drive : Google Drive
gmail : Gmail
```

Comment: Anytime I've done anything like this I generally create a custom post type. So you could create one for Software and then you can pull your choices into an ACF field as post objects in a repeater.